# How do I replace the 'Nest' text with my own application name when logging?

Tags: nestjs

The standard logging output with NestJS looks as follows:

```
[Nest] 1  - 01/01/2022, 2:54:40 PM     LOG [Main] Listening for HTTP requests on port 3000
```

Each line starts with '[Nest]'. Can I replace that with my own application name? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom logger for this. Either [extending Nest's own](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards) or using a pre-built solution like [ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma), [pino](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino), or [winston](https://github.com/gremo/nest-winston)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to extend Nest's logger following the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#extend-built-in-logger).

When you create your custom logger, override the formatPid function, like so.

```js
import { ConsoleLogger } from "@nestjs/common";

export class CompanyLogger extends ConsoleLogger {
  #appName = 'Company App'

  public setAppName (name: string): void {
    this.#appName = name
  }

  override formatPid(pid: number): string {
    return `[${this.#appName}] ${pid}  - `;
  }
}
```

When you bootstrap your app, you can set the custom name.

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  bufferLogs: true,
});

const logger = app.get(CompanyLogger)
logger.setAppName('OnlyCats')
app.useLogger(logger);
await app.listen(3000);
```

You should get the following

```bash
[OnlyCats] 31956  - 09/13/2023, 10:11:44 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started
```